# Extra method getting added to deployed web3 contract, while testing on previously deployed address

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

This is my contract's code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    function Inbox(string initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

I deployed the above contract to Goerli network and saved deployed address. After some time when I tried to interact with the previously deployed method, I found `doMath` method surprisingly got added in the deployed contract.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extra method (doMath) got added due to the fact that I changed my code in the editor between.

As FE apps requires `abi` to interact with the deployed contract, the newly updated `abi` from the editor was reflecting in the previously deployed contract.

As a thing to remember its important to paste the exact same solidity code in the editor, while interacting the deployed contract.